# Why I can not install firewalld on centos6?

Tags: centos6, firewalld

I am installing SSL certificate in my CentOS 6. In order to do that, I have to setup firewall rule.

But when I am setting up the firewall I get an error:

```
$ firewall-cmd --permanent --add-service=https
-bash: firewall-cmd: command not found.
```

It appears that only the command `iptables` works in CentOS 6.

I also tried to install firewalld using the command

```
$sudo yum install firewalld.
```

But it gives me the followingerror:

> No package firewalld available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firewalld is [only part of CentOS 7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewalld#Adoption).  It does not ship with, and afaik is not available for, CentOS 6.  If you really can't face dealing with `iptables` rules (which I personally feel are not all that difficult), [some people](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=57051) feel that `system-config-firewall` is an acceptable substitute.

Or just try

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
```

though depending on your existing ruleset, this may or may not play well.